# Including a .bat file or a .exe file inside the Windows application program

Tags: .net, batch-file, exe

Im doing a project in which im including an already done program.

It has a .bat file as well as a .exe file.

Now  the already done progream is in a folder 'X' where there are many files including

1. is a .tcl file
2. is a .exe file
3. is a .bat file.

now the when i click the .exe file it opens a dialogue box where i have to select the above mentioned .tcl file and the program executes.

now when i execute the .bat file the program executes automatically.

Now the problem is that all the files are inside a same folder. If i keep the .bat file or the .exe file out of the folder 'X' my already done program doesnt execute.

Now im doing a project where i have to call this so called already done program.

Im calling the .bat file or the .exe file. Inside the program using

```
Process.Start(@"E:\X\abc.exe");
```

or

```
Process.Start(@"E:\X\xyz.bat");
```

but my program doesnt execute.

so i added the whole folder 'X' inside my projects and tried this.

```
Process.Start(@"E:\Project\X\abc.exe");
```

or

```
Process.Start(@"E:\Project\X\xyz.bat");
```

where project is the folder where my projects get saved. Also note im using windows application.

both ways i dont get result.

I have kept the process.start for the button click event.

During the button click if i have

```
Process.Start(@"E:\Project\X\xyz.bat");
```

i get blink of the cmd prompt and nothing happens.

when i have

```
Process.Start(@"E:\Project\X\abc.exe");
```

i get the dialog box that i mentioned above. And i have to select the .tct file that i mentioned above.

But i get an error like this.

> couldn't open "./input-background.gif": no such file or directory

Is there a solution where i can run my program incluidng teh .bat file or the .exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I think may be there has some confuse problem in your scenario, so I will post a typical calling bat program here:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
    ProcessStartInfo pst = new ProcessStartInfo("Your batch file","the arguments"); 
    Process p = new Process(); 
    p.StartInfo = pst; Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput); //Some info like error message in your batch file or comments. 
p.Start(); 
    }
```

and you could replace Your batch file with an executable file or a batch file.
About your second problem, may be there has some resource in your batch file get a directory  with a space in it, your could add quota around it.
I suggest you could test your batch file in windows command line first, and if it works as expected, then turn to the Process code.
Hope help.

Comment: thanks a lot yar. but somehow i troubleshooted it and got the result.. i also tried your method,

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide error messages from your functions it's hard to understand what's wrong anyway you may try to run the processes changing their current directory (I guess they search something they can't find like "input-background.gif"). As example:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("YourProgram.exe", "command line parameters");
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
 Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: I didnt get any error. the only error i got was "couldn't open "./input-background.gif": no such file or directory". That is the problem. I also tried ur method but it doesnt work

Comment: same thing happens with your method also. just get a blink of the cmd prompt when the .bat file executes.

Comment: Redirect batch file output to a file (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) to get what the batch _says_ (can you include the batch code?)

Answer (score 0):

Agree the previous answer, and more thing I want to mention is, if your app is running under windows7 or higher, please notice Windows User Account Control (UAC), shut it down or run your app with Admin privilege. Otherwise the process object will not run.

Comment: im using XP professional. But still get the same thing. Any other suggestion.